# Same GameObject Two AudioSources Not Playing Their AudioClips - Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, audio-source

I was working on 3d runner kind of game so I have attached two AudioSources component within Player GameObject:

1. AudioSource for playing gameplay music
2. AudioSource for playing player collision sound

On same Player GameObject, I have assigned two AudioSources for playing these two sounds but at present only GamePlay music is playing, Player collision sound not gets played when it collide with obstacles.

[image]

Both AudioSources have their assigned AudioClips.

On collision time with an obstacle, I was playing collision sound like this way:

```
void OnCollisionEnter (Collision other)
{
    if (other.transform.CompareTag (GameConstants.TAG_OBSTACLE)) {
        Vector3 splashEffectPos = groundCheck.position;
        if (splashEffectPos.y < 0.05f)
            splashEffectPos.y = 0.05f;

        // stop game music
        if (SoundManager.Instance.EnableSound) {
            gameSoundAS.Play ();
            gameMusicAS.Stop ();
//          gameSoundAS.PlayOneShot (ballCollisionClip);
        }

        GameObject splash = Instantiate (splashEffectPrefab, splashEffectPos, Quaternion.identity);
        splash.transform.SetParent (GameController.Instance.transform);

        GameController.Instance.GameOver ();
        gameObject.SetActive (false);
    }
}
```

GamePlay music is playing properly and get stopped when it collide with an obstacle but Player collision sound is not playing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I managed to solve the problem myself. If GameObject becomes disabled then its AudioSources isn't able to play.

In the `OnCollisionEnter` method above, I have disabled my Player GameObject so AudioSource won't produce any sound.

Comment: If you solved your own question, you should select your answer as the solution so future people know how you solved it.

Comment: I have not selected this as true because of waiting time from stack overflow - at same time I can't able to mark my answer as correct - I require to wait for 2 days